# ember-data not available in app.js

Tags: ember-data

I downloaded ember-data repo, ran bundle and rake dist, then picked up the ember-data.js file from the dist folder. I put it in my ember app. Now trying the following code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('about');
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11
});
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DS is not defined
```

I am new to javascript as well. This might be a javascript error. I can get the DS.Store in the console by typing window.DS.Store or this.DS.Store. Why is it not available in app.js?

This is index file:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure meanwhile your problem is solved but for the records:

You have to change the order of how your javascript is loaded. In your case `app.js` is icluded before `ember-data.js` so `app.js` does not know anything about ember-data.

```
<script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```